# Why no operations on subtrees are allowed in "Child references"

Tags: mongodb

Why no operations on subtrees are allowed in [Model Tree Structures with Child References](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/model-tree-structures-with-child-references/)?

Comment: Oh, I see. They mean you can't mutate the tree structure itself rather than the data in the elements of the tree. Ok makes sense.